# How to get metadata (in my case mail) of users who have a certain set of metadata?

Tags: user-meta

It's a really hectic day for me. Okay, I need to choose all users with some role, with and with some meta_data: subscriber, user_country, and user_sector for example.

In the beginning, I have several parameters: $role, $sector, $country Now I need to filter users by these parameters. At first, the task was to filter users by roles only. I did it this way:

```
 $role = get_option('choosed_users_role'); //I get this from the database
 $subscribers = get_users( $role );
 $emails      = array ();
 foreach ( $subscribers as $subscriber ){
     $emails[] = $subscriber->user_email;
 }
```

This way I get all mail of the users with the specific role. When it became necessary to add two more parameters I thought that in this way I can add other parameters for filtering.

```
$subscribers = get_users( $role) && get_users( $sector) && get_users(  user_country);
```

But it's not right I see now. What's the correct way to do this? Please help to figure out with it.

PS:

By advice Rup I tried using WP_User_Query:

```
$params = array(
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'user-country',
                        'value'   => '17',
                        'type'    => 'numeric',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'user-sector',
                        'value'   => '602',
                        'type'    => 'numeric',
                    )
                )
            );
```

But not the result. I think the WP_User_Query does not work because I try to get a custom ACF meta field.

Comment: Here's the documentation for the parameter array that get_users() accepts, if that helps? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/prepare_query/ You should be able to do this all in a single query.

Comment: No, I'm sorry the WP_User_Query is not for my case I see, there are some custom meta created with ACF and I can not get it using WP_User_Query(

Comment: I thought the ACF fields were in user_meta, but maybe with a prefix? (just an underscore?) I'd check the database table to see.